# Star Wars: The Old Republic starts up to green screen and hangs

Tags: technical-issues, star-wars-the-old-republic, windows

I'm trying to play Star Wars: The Old Republic, but upon launching the game my screen turns green after the loading screen, and stays like that for minutes with no signs of anything changing. What can I do to resolve this? I'm on Windows 10 with an AMD Radeon RX 570. I've tried updating my drivers to the latest version available, deleting client_settings.ini, using DXVK, verifying the game through Steam, and manually installing DirectX 9.0c. None of this helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by editing client_settings.ini and changing the  `NativeWidth`, `NativeHeight`, `Width`, and `Height` fields. My monitor is 1920x1080, but for some reason both width values (`NativeWidth`, `Width`) were set to 3840 and both height values (`NativeHeight`, `Height`) were set to 2160 (i.e. a resolution of 3840x2160). Setting both height values to 1920 and both width values to 1080 and then saving my changes made the game start up properly.

client_settings.ini can be found by pressing Windows + R, then entering `%localappdata%\swtor\swtor\settings` in the window that opens and pressing enter. This should open a folder containing client_settings.ini.